# Testing multiple scenarios in tastypie

Tags: django, unit-testing, tastypie

I need to test a scenario where a user gets registered then tries to login with the same credentials.

I've designed a test such as follows

```
class UserFlow(ResourceTestCase):  
    loginEmail='name@domain.com'
    loginPassword='abc'
    def setUp(self):
        ResourceTestCase.setUp(self)  
    @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
    def test_userFlow(self):
        current_Count = LCUser.objects.count()
        self.assertValidJSONResponse(self.api_client.post('/register/', format='json', data={'email':self.loginEmail,'password':self.loginPassword}))
        self.assertEqual(LCUser.objects.count(), (current_Count+1))
        resp = self.api_client.post('/login/', format='json', data={'email':self.loginEmail,'password':self.loginPassword})
        self.assertValidJSONResponse(resp)
```

I can see that the registration succeeds but the login test fails. I have tried running the test by hand and the API works fine. It's almost as if the test does not save the registered user prior to executing login. Any idea why this is happening ?

Output show that the last test (the login test) `self.assertValidJSONResponse(resp)` fails

The test fails on

```
resp = self.api_client.post('/login/', format='json', data={'email':self.loginEmail,'password':self.loginPassword}‌​) 
self.assertValidJSONResponse(resp)
```

`resp.content` shows my custom error:

> Username or Password incorrect

Comment: U mean both count are different...?

Comment: You should format your error as JSON instead of just a string: {"error": "Username or Password incorrect"}